# Xamarin Forms: ToolBarItem on left for both iOS and Android

Tags: xamarin, renderer, toolbaritems

I'm trying to find a way to put a close ToolBarItem on the left of my ToolBar.
To be more explicit, here are some screenshots:

For Android:
[image]

For iOS:
[image]

The problem is not about to display icon istead of text, I'm using Iconize for that. The problem is about to put ToolBarItem to the left for both iOS and Android.

I've found this renderer for iOS (not tried yet):
https://gist.github.com/alexlau811/f1fff9e726333e6b4a2f

Comment: Did you figure out the solution for Android?

Comment: I added a simple toolbar icon displayed on the right (this is the default place for toolbar item) and added a click event to close the page. I did not find a way to add close button on the to left.

Comment: Alright thanks. Guess I'll have to go with custom navigation renderer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write Custom renderer to implement left side tool bar items. Detailed implementation for this is explained here   https://timeyoutake.it/2016/01/02/creating-a-left-toolbaritem-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: That's close to the same thing I've posted for iOS. Any idea for Android ?

Comment: Any thing for Android?